# Graphic clipping of Data Driven Pages to index feature that defines each page?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, data-driven-pages, definition-query

I wonder if there is a way to cut all the data in each polygon separately when using data driven pages?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can add a polygon layer on top that is all white and has the same polygons as what you have encircled. You then make a Page Definition Query that is based on the page name (requires a field in the new polygon FC with that info, should be "trivial" to accomplish with a spatial join if necessary). You set it to show all but the one where the name corresponds to current page name, se image.

[image]

Comment: NOTE: you would want the fill to be white and no outline. To get the polygon boundaries (the one for the page) to show you might just make a put that one layer on top of the "do not match" layer.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily clip data outside of your current Data Driven Page polygon.

To do this, go into your Data Frame Properties and go to the "Data Frame" tab.  Set the "Clip Options" to "Clip to current data driven page extent."  You can choose to set a border around the clipping polygon area.

[image]

If you want some layers to display outside of your current Data Driven page polygon, you can choose those in the "Exclude Layers" box.  This will exclude the layers from being clipped.